# Alternative for a stored procedure for recursion in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using the recursive function below which will loop for more than 4500 times. In each iteration the code will extract more than 50 records.

```
WITH RECURSIVE RECEMP (
    EMP_ID,
    EMP_DB,
    lvl,
    LEVEL
    )
AS (
    SELECT EMP_ID,
        EMP_DB,
        lvl,
        1 (INT)
    FROM EDW_MAN_WORK.emp --WHERE EMP_ID = 12

    UNION ALL

    SELECT E.EMP_ID,
        E.EMP_DB,
        E.lvl,
        R.LEVEL + 1
    FROM EDW_MAN_WORK.emp E
    INNER JOIN RECEMP R
        ON E.EMP_ID = R.EMP_ID
            AND R.LEVEL <= r.lvl
    )
SELECT EMP_ID,
    EMP_DB,
    Lvl,
    LEVEL
FROM RECEMP
```

My query is failing because of a SPOOL space error. Can we collect stats on recursive table?

I have tried this with a stored procedure as well, but again this is very time consuming.

Please suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: Your query fails because it returns each row lvl + 1 times, so you could easily rewrite it using a cross join to a a number table. But why do you need this result set? Can you elaborate what you actually try to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you can not collect stats on a CTE in Teradata.

It appears that your join between the CTE and the `EMP` table may be introducing an infinite loop. I don't fully understand the relationship you are trying to build but it would seem to me that on the surface your join between the CTE and `EMP` should be `E.EMP_DB = R.EMP_ID`. Again I'm making a big assumption here that the relationship you are trying to map out with the recursion is between `EMP_DB` and `EMP_ID`.

Nonetheless, I would suggest that you place a limit on the depth of your recursion as a safeguard. This may help you run the query and get some results back before the query runs out of spool space. See below:

```
WITH RECURSIVE RECEMP (
    EMP_ID,
    EMP_DB,
    lvl,
    LEVEL
    )
AS (
    SELECT EMP_ID,
        EMP_DB,
        lvl,
        1 (INT)
    FROM EDW_MAN_WORK.emp --WHERE EMP_ID = 12

    UNION ALL

    SELECT E.EMP_ID,
        E.EMP_DB,
        E.lvl,
        R.LEVEL + 1
    FROM EDW_MAN_WORK.emp E
    INNER JOIN RECEMP R
        ON E.EMP_ID = R.EMP_ID
            AND R.LEVEL <= r.lvl
           /* Depth Control - You expect a depth <= 50 */
           AND R.LEVEL = 60
    )
SELECT EMP_ID,
    EMP_DB,
    Lvl,
    LEVEL
FROM RECEMP
```